# ckeditor: how to remove tags inside other specific tags

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm searching through the whole documentation of ckeditor since 1 1/2 days, but I can't find the solution.

So far I've configured the ckeditor to my requirements, and the ACF (Advanced Content Filter) is working too.

**My Problem for now is:**
If I insert from an external source e.g. this:

```
<table style="padding-left: 0px;">
<tr style="vertical-align: top;">
    <td style="text-align: left;" width="179">
        <p style="padding-bottom: 0px;">Gewicht Brutto</p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The ckeditor filters out all the attributes (which is totally fine) and gives me this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <p>Gewicht Brutto</p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But I can't find a way to remove the `<p>`-Tag, if - and **only** if it's inside a `<td>` (I don't want to remove all `<p>`'s and I'm also fine with the "insert `<p>` on enter)

With all the [ACF-configurations-stuff](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf) I can only define which tags are allowed or disallowed, or which attributes can be used.

Does anyone know if there is a way to also remove unwanted elements in specific parent-elements?

Thanks a lot!
Martin

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

You can use the '*match*' property ( if you define rules as an object ), defining it in the disallowedContent. So that means, whenever the match function rule returns true, those element will be filtered out.

**Sample example:**

It removes all br elements from td elements ( having parent as a td element). You should note, that in this case the element parameter is not yet atteched to the DOM, so it is only a htmlParser.element.

```
'br' : {
         match: function( element ) {
            var aParent = element.getAncestor(),
                aParentTagName = aParent.name;

            if( typeof aParentTagName === 'string' &&
                  aParentTagName.toUpperCase() == 'TD' ) {
                   return true;
            }

            return false;
         }
       }
```

**Other options exits as well:**

1. Run a *custom cleanup* code after insertion ( you will be run your
   code on DOM nodes )
2. Define CKEDITOR.toHtml event, but make sure you are using a before filtered priority number. How to found here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-toHtml
3. Define *CKEDITOR.pasteFilter*, which only filters external pasted data. How to found here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-property-pasteFilter